# Send new mail with another mail as attachment using EWS

Tags: soap, office365, exchangewebservices, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm working on 'outlook-web-addon' that take the currently opened message and attache it to a new message and send it to a specific address.. all without allowing the user to interact (No compose screen)

The code below is passed till 'Create attachment' which generate the error:
"The requested web method is unavailable to this caller or application"

```
function sendMessage() {
    //$("#y").load("x.html");
    //var mailBody = document.load("MailBody");
    //<object type="text/html" data="mailBody.html"></object>

    if (Office.context.mailbox.item.itemType !== Office.MailboxEnums.ItemType.Message) {
        return;
    }

    var parentId='';
    var mimeContent='';

    //Get current selected mail message Id
    var mailbox = Office.context.mailbox;
    var item = mailbox.item;
    var itemId = item.itemId;


    //1- Create Mime content from the current selected mail message
    var request_MimeContent =
        '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
            '    <soap:Body>' +
            '       <m:GetItem>' +
            '           <m:ItemShape>' +
            '               <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>' +
            '               <t:AdditionalProperties>' +
            '                   <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:MimeContent" />' +
            '                   <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Subject" />' +
            '               </t:AdditionalProperties>' +
            '           </m:ItemShape>' +
            '           <m:ItemIds>' +
            '               <t:ItemId Id="' +itemId +'" />' +
            '           </m:ItemIds>' +
            '       </m:GetItem>' +
            '    </soap:Body>' +
            '</soap:Envelope>';
    Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(request_MimeContent, createMail);
}

function createMail(asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.status == "failed") {
        return;
    } else {
        //2- Get MimeContent
        var response = $.parseXML(asyncResult.value);
        window.mimeContent = response.getElementsByTagName("MimeContent");

        //3- Create mail request
        var request_CreateMail =
            '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
                '  <soap:Header><t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010" /></soap:Header>' +
                '  <soap:Body>' +
                '    <m:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SaveOnly">' +
                '      <m:SavedItemFolderId><t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="sentitems" /></m:SavedItemFolderId>' +
                '      <m:Items>' +
                '        <t:Message>' +
                '          <t:Subject>Phishing Mail Report!</t:Subject>' +
                '          <t:Body BodyType="HTML">This is a Test !!</t:Body>' +
                '          <t:ToRecipients>' +
                '            <t:Mailbox><t:EmailAddress>M.Ziada@Zinad.net</t:EmailAddress></t:Mailbox>' +
                '          </t:ToRecipients>' +
                '        </t:Message>' +
                '      </m:Items>' +
                '    </m:CreateItem>' +
                '  </soap:Body>' +
                '</soap:Envelope>';
        Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(request_CreateMail, createAttachment);
    }
}

function createAttachment(asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.status == "failed") {
        return;
    } else {
        //4- Get new message Id
        var response = $.parseXML(asyncResult.value);
        window.parentId = response.getElementsByTagName("ItemId");

        //5- Create attachment from the mime content and belongs to the new message
        var request_CreateAttachment =
            '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
                '    <soap:Header><t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010" /></soap:Header>' +
                '    <soap:Body>' +
                '       <m:CreateAttachment>' +
                '           <m:ParentItemId Id="' +window.parentId +'" />' +
                '           <m:Attachments>' +
                '               <t:ItemAttachment>' +
                '                   <t:Name>Play tennis?</t:Name>' +
                '                   <t:IsInline>false</t:IsInline>' +
                '                   <t:Message>' +
                '                       <t:MimeContent CharacterSet="UTF-8">' +window.mimeContent +'</t:MimeContent>' +
                '                   </t:Message>' +
                '               </t:ItemAttachment>' +
                '           </m:Attachments>' +
                '       </m:CreateAttachment>' +
                '    </soap:Body>' +
                '</soap:Envelope>';
        Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(request_CreateAttachment, sendItem);
    }
}

function sendItem(asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.status == "failed") {
        return;
    } else {
        //6- Get attachment Id
        var response = $.parseXML(asyncResult.value);
        var attachmentId = response.getElementsByTagName("AttachmentId");

        //7- Send newly created message
        var request_SendItem =
            '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
                '    <soap:Header><t: RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010" /></soap:Header>' +
                '    <soap:Body>' +
                '       <m:SendItem SaveItemToFolder="true">' +
                '           <m:ItemIds>' +
                '               <t:ItemId Id="' +window.parentId +'"/>' +
                '           </m:ItemIds>' +
                '           <m:SavedItemFolderId>' +
                '               <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="sentitems" />' +
                '           </m:SavedItemFolderId>' +
                '       </m:SendItem>' +
                '    </soap:Body>' +
                '</soap:Envelope>';
        Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(request_SendItem,
            function(asyncResult2) {
                if (asyncResult2.status == "failed") {
                    return;
                } else {
                }
            });
    }
}
```

I'm trying on Chrome, and it gives me this error:
"The requested web method is unavailable to this caller or application"

Also, I wonder if this will work on desktop outlook application ?

Answer (score 2):

As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/understanding-outlook-add-in-permissions#readwritemailbox-permission the attachment operations aren't allowed with MakeEWSRequestAsync. There is a ReadOnly method you can use for accessing attachments https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/get-attachments-of-an-outlook-item (but I don't believe this will allow you to create one).

The only workaround I know is that because CreateItem is allowed and you can create a Message from the MIMEContent if the message that you want to send is built in Mime first (with the attachment mime encoded) and then you create the Message from that content it should work.